# Dynamically pass column name to SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I was wondering if is possible to pass the column name of a table so I can create a dynamic query for my stored procedure. I will appreciate any help!

Good query:

```
SELECT
A1,
LEFT (A1,CHARINDEX(',',A1)-1) AS UPC,
SUBSTRING(A1,CHARINDEX(',', A1 , 1)  + 1,LEN(A1) - CHARINDEX(',', A1) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(A1))) AS Date,
SUBSTRING(A1,CHARINDEX(',', A1 , 1)  + 7,LEN(A1) - CHARINDEX(',', A1) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(A1))) AS Qty
FROM Registry Where Id=26
```

Output:

```
 A1              UPC      Date    Qty
-------------------------------------
CPU1,01/15,3     CPU1     01/15   3
```

This is what I have so far for the stored procedure

SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_UPD_Compartment] 
@Id  int, 
@Col_Name char(40) 

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
@Col_Name,
LEFT (@Col_Name,CHARINDEX(',',@Col_Name)-1) AS UPC,
SUBSTRING(@Col_Name,CHARINDEX(',', @Col_Name , 1)  + 1,LEN(@Col_Name) - CHARINDEX(',', @Col_Name) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@Col_Name))) AS Date,
SUBSTRING(@Col_Name,CHARINDEX(',', @Col_Name , 1)  + 7,LEN(@Col_Name) - CHARINDEX(',', @Col_Name) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@Col_Name))) AS Qty
FROM Registry Where Id=@Id

END
```

Error msg:

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SP_UPD_Compartment, Line 9
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Comment: Read a little about sp_executesql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am typing from tab, so there may be some syntax mistakes, but i think you will get the idea. First you create a string with your statement and then replace substring '@Col_Name' with passed parameter to procedure. Then you execute that dynamic sql. You can also add `Print @cmd` before `EXEC(@cmd)` to see what actually will be executed.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_UPD_Compartment] 
@Id  INT, 
@Col_Name CHAR(40) 

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(4000) =
'SELECT
@Col_Name,
LEFT (@Col_Name,CHARINDEX('','',@Col_Name)-1) AS UPC,
SUBSTRING(@Col_Name,CHARINDEX('','', @Col_Name , 1)  + 1,LEN(@Col_Name) - CHARINDEX('','', @Col_Name) - CHARINDEX('','', REVERSE(@Col_Name))) AS Date,
SUBSTRING(@Col_Name,CHARINDEX('','', @Col_Name , 1)  + 7,LEN(@Col_Name) - CHARINDEX('','', @Col_Name) - CHARINDEX('','', REVERSE(@Col_Name))) AS Qty
FROM Registry WHERE Id=' + CAST(@Id AS NVARCHAR(20))

SET @cmd = REPLACE(@cmd, '@Col_Name', @Col_Name)
EXEC(@cmd)

END
```

Comment: @Carlos, you could write directly `'Update Registry Set @Col_Name = LEFT (@Col_Name,CHARINDEX('','',@Col_Name)-1) + '','' + LEFT (@Col_Name,CHARINDEX('','',@Col_Name)-1)' ` . Now you don't need replace for comma.